# How can i resolve implicitly typed variable error?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
   var dbColumns =  null; 

  dbColumns = dbColumnsCollection.Where(s => s.Field1 == "test");
```

but get an error "cannot assign   to an implicitly typed variable"

How can I initialize the variable dbColumns ?

thanks

Comment: `var dbColumns =  null;` Ask yourself this - if you had **just** that line of code what would the type of `dbColumns` be?

Comment: The code you want is `var dbColumns = dbColumnsCollection.Where(s => s.Field1 == "test");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because C# is strongly type. And var is used for [anonymous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). Thus declaring a null for a var cannot and will not work.

So Code like this just won't work out because the compiler can't detect the datatype of dbColumns.

```
var dbColumns =  null;
```

Two ways to declare dbColumns,

First if you want to retain the variable then use

```
var dbColumns =  (IEnumerable<PocoClass>)null;
```

or the reliable good ol way

```
 IEnumerable<PocoClass> dbColumns =  null
```

EDIT: 
You may also still use `IQueryable` if you are still building the LINQ query.